# Multiple variable linear regression on election/census data & resulting errors

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I have this data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  "racecmb" = c("White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
            "White", "White", "Black", "White", "Mixed", 
            "Black", "White", "White", "White"),
  "age" = c(77,74,55,62,60,59,32,91,75,73,43,67,58,18,57),
  "income" = c("10 to under $20,000", "100 to under $150,000", 
           "75 to under $100,000",  "75 to under $100,000",
           "10 to under $20,000", "20 to under $30,000",
           "100 to under $150,000", "20 to under $30,000",
           "100 to under $150,000", "20 to under $30,000",
           "100 to under $150,000", "Less than $10,000",
           "$150,000 or more", " 30 to under $40,000",
           "50 to under $75,000"),
  "party" = c("Independent", "Independent", "Independent", "Democrat", 
          "Independent", "Republican", "Independent", 
          "Independent", "Democrat", "Republican", "Republican", 
          "Democrat", "Democrat", "Independent", "Independent"),
 "ideology" = c("Moderate", "Moderate", "Conservative", "Moderate", 
             "Moderate", "Very conservative", "Moderate", 
             "Conservative", 
             "Conservative", "Moderate", "Conservative", 
             "Very conservative", "Liberal", "Moderate", "Conservative")
             )
```

I want (have tried) to run a simple multiple regression:

```
regression <- lm(party ~ income + ideo + age, data = df) %>%
   summary()
```

I get this error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

My goal is to explain the way some people vote, but I don't see how to effectively code the data for my model.

Any comments/suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: you seem to be trying to fit a linear model with a categorical response. That doesn't make much sense. Can you describe what you are trying to do? Also, make sure to share sample data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it can be copy/pasted into R for testing. The spaces in your sample data make this hard.

Comment: So should I be using `glm()` instead of `lm()`? I guess that would make more sense

Comment: Also made it reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to begin with, using `lm()` for categorical variables is not ideal. What you're looking to use is either `rpart()` which will give you output as categories or classes, or you can use multinomial logit/probit regression to return probabilities of outcomes occuring given some conditions.

*Packages to install: rpart and statisticalModeling*

If you did not have a categorical response variable, you could convert your categorical variables into dummy variables and then run your regression including your dummy variables (*remember to leave one as baseline*).

This can be quickly achieved using the `fastDummies` package:

*Example:* `df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "ideology")`

If your sample size is considerable, then you may also want to consider interactions in your model between the dummied variables!

Comment: Interactions can be coded with the `:` in the formula, right? And thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, when I try the dummy conversion, it just gives me the error: `Error in stopifnot(is.null(select_columns) || is.character(select_columns),  : 
  object 'ideology' not found` - is this because the variable is a factor?

Comment: I seem to have made a mistake in my code. The column name is supposed to be in quotation marks! So it is supposed to be: `df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "ideology")`. Factors should be fine to pass through the function. Interactions can be written as `:` or `*`. The difference is that `*` is shorthand for `X1 + X2 + X1:X2`. So if you only want certain interactions using `:` is safer.